# Translating jQuery toggle code to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to translate some jQuery to toggle a button/responsive menu and just can't get my version to work. I know most people are pretty jazzed about jQuery but we aren't allowed to use it in our class projects, so I really need to understand the how/why of my code not working.

**jQuery Code:**

```
var content = $('main');
$('button').click(function () {
    ($('i').hasClass('fa-bars')) ?
    $('i').removeClass('fa-bars').addClass('fa-times'):
        $('i').removeClass('fa-times').addClass('fa-bars');
    $('ul').toggleClass('nav-visible');
    content.toggleClass('active');
});
```

**JavaScript Code:**

```
var content = document.querySelector('main');
var button = document.querySelector('button');

function clickListener(button) {
    "use strict";
    button.addEventListener('click', function () {
        var i = document.querySelector('i');
        if (i.contains('fa fa-bars') === true) {
            i.remove('fa fa-bars');
            i.add('fa fa-times');
        } else {
            i.remove('fa fa-times');
            i.add('fa fa-bars');
        }
        var ul = document.querySelector('ul');
        ul.toggleClass('nav-visible');
        content.toggleClass('active');
    });
}
```

However, the jQuery equivalent code in JavaScript is not working.

Comment: where is clickListener called? I only see its declaration

Comment: @Sindico  -  I don't think I call the clickListener.

Answer (score 2):

1. Use `querySelector` to select an element
2. `addEventListner` to bind event
3. `classList` API to add, remove, has and toggle a class.

**jQuery Code:**

```
var content = $('main');
$('button').click(function () {
    ($('i').hasClass('fa-bars')) ? $('i').removeClass('fa-bars').addClass('fa-times'):
         $('i').removeClass('fa-times').addClass('fa-bars');
    // This is same as
    // $('i').toggleClass('fa-times fa-bars');


    $('ul').toggleClass('nav-visible');
    content.toggleClass('active');
});
```

**Equivalent JavaScript Code:**

```
var content = document.querySelector('main'); // Same as $('main')

// bind click event on first <button> element
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {

    // Toggle classes
    document.querySelector('i').classList.toggle('fa-bars');
    document.querySelector('i').classList.toggle('fa-times');

    document.querySelector('ul').classList.toggle('nav-visible');
    content.classList.toggle('active');
}, false);
```

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/1tcj99uu/)

Comment: Note: this will only work if you only have one `<main>`, one `<button>`, one `<i>`, one `<ul>`. jQuery makes you not worry about plurality; if you have multiple of any of those, you'd need to use `querySelectorAll` and iteration. It also makes some reasonable assumptions about `.fa-bars` and `.fa-times` being complementary, and untouched by any other manipulation.

Comment: @Tushar I tried your code and it still isn't working. I have a code pen with the jQuery and one with the JS. I think based on a comment above i still need to call the clickListener but haven't implemented it correctly.   Nav Reveal (JS) 
http://codepen.io/aaknitta/pen/MyEoLa

Nav Reveal (JQuery)
http://codepen.io/aaknitta/pen/aNLyLq

Comment: @agaluser i've updated answer. Check [**this demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/1tcj99uu/)